# Shared library, common functions

Tags: shared-libraries

I am building two shared libraries which has same function names with different implementations.

lib-xyz.so

lib-abc.so, I am builing application with with lib-xyz.so. In the application I am loading lib-abc.so using dlopen. Both the libraries have functions with same names and global variables.

When I am runing application The function in lib-abc.so is calling common function in lib-xyz.so instead of its own(lib-xyz.so). Same the case with globale structure.can any one tell how to resolve this issue and confine share library address space.

Comment: I believe your design is wrong. `dlopen`-ing a library with same names as an initially linked library is asking for big trouble... Can't you do otherwise (e.g. compile `lib-xyz.so` with a bunch of `#define` renaming the common names....) ???

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These are third part libraries which has lot of common symbols. Is there any way to limit the scope of calls within the share lib. Same aproach is working with Andorid. What is the diffrence bettwen android and Linux dynamic linking.